# В чем смысл NAT, если есть подсети?

Tags: сеть, nat

Правильно ли я понимаю, что NAT призван решить проблему количества адресов, так как подсети с этим не справляются?

Comment: NAT призван решить проблему количества адресов, так как на каждый компьютер не выделишь уникальный белый IP адрес, так как их просто не хватит. Поэтому локальные сети компаний и даже клиенты некоторых провайдеров находятся за NAT. Ну и плюс это дополнительная безопасность.

Comment: @nightflash согласен, но в чем проблема с подсетями? Приходит пакет на внешний IP-адрес, накладывается маска подсети и вот уже есть локальный IP-адрес, который не маршрутизируется в глобальной сети.

Comment: Ну так оно так и делается. NAT транслирует в локальную сеть с локальными адресами. Никакой проблемы в этом нет. Или я не понял вопроса :)

Comment: @nightflash Оно-то транслируется, но не таким образом. В случае с маской подсети, прилетает пакет на маршрутизатор, он накладывает маску, из нее получается адрес подсети и адрес хоста. В случае с NAT, прилетает пакет на маршрутизатор, он достает порт источника из TCP заголовка и ищет локальный адрес с помощью порта источника. Так вот я и не понимаю, вроде бы решают одну задачу, но применяются ведь вместе, возможно, я не прав, но не понимаю в чем.

Comment: Нет, задачи разные. В первом случае пришлось бы каждому компьютеру за маршрутизатором давать уникальный IP-адрес. А их как раз и не хватает.

Comment: @nightflash каждому устройству и так даётся уникальный IP-адрес в локальной сети.

Comment: @nightflash может я не понимаю, как работают подсети, но, насколько я понял, как только на маршрутизатор прилетает пакет, он накидывает маску и уже получается адрес, который уникальный для подсети, но он не маршрутизируется в глобальной сети.

Comment: Я что-то не могу понять логики «накладывает маску, из нее получается адрес подсети и адрес хоста», как это вообще. Можно пример на каких-нибудь конкретных адресах и подсетях?

Comment: @kaylil_01 Уникальный в пределах локальной сети, но не глобальной.

Comment: @andreymal не совсем удобно говорить о конкретных адресах, но, насколько я понимаю, делается логическое умножение маски и адреса из нее становится понятен, адрес подсети. Хотя я вот сейчас подумал, откуда ему взять адрес хоста? Но тогда вопрос другой, для чего вообще маска подсети?

Comment: @nightflash в обоих случаях уникальные адреса локальной сети, но не глобальной.

Comment: @kaylil_01 «для чего вообще маска подсети» — порылся в гугле, кажется тут достаточно толково рассказано http://codeart.ru/2008/05/04/maska-podseti-vy-uvereny-chto-ponimaete-dlya-chego-ona-nuzhna/

Comment: Что-то я не понял. Вот на роутер пришёл пакет на адрес 1.2.3.4:80. Какую маску и на что он должен наложить что бы выбрать на какой из трёх телефонов, двух ноутбуков и телевизора нужно отправить пакет дальше?

Comment: *Вот на роутер пришёл пакет на адрес 1.2.3.4:80. Какую маску и на что он должен наложить что бы выбрать на какой из трёх телефонов, двух ноутбуков и телевизора нужно отправить пакет дальше?* Никакую. Сначала он посмотрит таблицу активных исходящих соединений - если там есть соответствие, отправит по нему. Если нет - посмотрит таблицу сопоставления портов, если есть соответствие, отправит по нему. Иначе - либо тихо дропнет пакет, либо обратно отправит "Ты куда, болван, стучишься?". Всё.

Comment: @Akina это NAT. Я же пытаюсь у автора узнать как он себе представляем маску сети

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы понимаете неправильно.

Подсети — это вообще не про решение проблем с количеством адресов. Подсети — это про разделение сети на сегменты и последующую организацию пропуска трафика между этими сегментами через настройку маршрутизации. При этом вообще между терминами "сеть", "подсеть" и "блок адресов" в контексте адресации особой разницы нет.

Хорошая иллюстрация этого утверждения — IPv6. Проблем с количеством адресов там нет (поэтому и NAT там притянут ну о-очень за уши), а сети/подсети есть :)